# how do i verify a row before and after update

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Need to code in a way that if a buyer buys quantity more than inventory console should display a message that you can buy only available quantity as of now, rest of the quantity will be updated soon, also if the inventory is sufficient to buy it should display please go ahead

In short,  "function, procedure to verify the quantity on hand before insert a row in table order_line and to update also the quantity on hand of table inventory"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE order_package IS
          global_inv_id NUMBER (6);
          global_quantity NUMBER (6);
    PROCEDURE create_new_order(current_c_id NUMBER,
 current_meth_pmt VARCHAR2, current_os_id NUMBER);
   PROCEDURE create_new_order_line(current_o_id NUMBER);
       END;
        /


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY order_package IS

    PROCEDURE create_new_order(current_c_id NUMBER,
 current_meth_pmt VARCHAR2, current_os_id NUMBER) AS
         current_o_id NUMBER;
       BEGIN
         SELECT order_seq.NEXTVAL
         INTO  current_o_id
         FROM   dual;
           INSERT INTO orders
     VALUES(current_o_id, sysdate,current_meth_pmt, current_c_id,
       current_os_id);
          COMMIT;
       create_new_order_line(current_o_id);
       END create_new_order;
   PROCEDURE create_new_order_line(current_o_id NUMBER)AS
       BEGIN
       INSERT INTO order_line
    VALUES(current_o_id,global_inv_id, global_quantity);
         COMMIT;
        END create_new_order_line;
       END;
        /
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your inventory table and your procedures don't seem to have a quantity ordered value, so some of this is conjecture. What you might want to do is first update that table and use the `RETURNING INTO` clause to get the updated inventory.

```
UPDATE inventory SET global_quantity = global_quantity - order_quantity
 WHERE global_inv_id = current_c_id
RETURNING global_quantity INTO l_global_quantity;

IF l_global_quantity < 0 THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'You ordered too much!' );
ELSE
    [... create order goes here ...]
END IF;
```

Is `current_c_id` is the item being ordered? This will raise an exception, which should be caught by whatever is calling your procedure. How you display the error to the user will depend on the application layer being used.

Comment: This is my order table:

Comment: order table: CREATE TABLE orders(o_id NUMBER(8), o_date DATE,o_methpmt VARCHAR2(10),c_id NUMBER(5),os_id NUMBER(3),                                                                                              
         and this is order line table                                                                                      CREATE TABLE order_line (o_id NUMBER(8), inv_id NUMBER(10), ol_quantity NUMBER(4) NOT NULL, and this is inventory table     CREATE TABLE inventory
(inv_id NUMBER(10),item_id NUMBER(8),color VARCHAR2(20),inv_size VARCHAR2(10),inv_price NUMBER(6,2),inv_qoh NUMBER(4),

Comment: current_c_id is the customer id